# Live Streaming on WindowsPhone8

Tags: xaml, c#-4.0, windows-phone-8, live-streaming

I am developing wp8 app,In that i need to play live-streaming of video.Can any one give samples or tutorials to play live streaming on wp8 app.
 I followed below link but its not working
https://playerframework.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Getting%20Started:%20WP8%20Smooth%20Streaming%20Player
Regards
chandu

Answer (score 1):

You have plenty of options:

Option 1: Here is a good tutorial that explains how to implement video streaming using the Smooth Streaming Client SDK: http://mingfeiy.com/building-windows-store-apps-smooth-streaming-client-sdk-beta-2

Option 2: Another approach is to use the Player Framework for Windows 8 Metro Style Applications To summarize, this is an open source, robust video player framework for Windows 8, HTML5, Silverlight, Windows Phone and other application platforms. 
Find it here: http://www.geekchamp.com/marketplace/components/media-platform-player-framework

Option 3: A Simple Windows 8 Smooth Streaming Media Player with a Slider Bar Control as in here : http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/A-simple-Windows-8-Smooth-ee98f63a

To summarize: This sample shows how to use Smooth Streaming Client SDK for Windows 8 to create a Windows Store application to playback Smooth Streaming content. In the sample, the MediaElement control is used to show the media content, and a slider bar control is used to control the progress. That`s is from me, just pick one of the options and you are ready to go.